# How to remove text "Redirected from Main Page" in MediaWiki?

Tags: mediawiki

MediaWiki's main page has the URL of

> site.com/wiki/index.php?title=Main_Page

and a gigantic header that reads Main Page.  The official way to rename Main Page is by moving the Main Page article to an article with a new name, plus a redirect.  However, doing that adds a phrase

> (Redirected from Main Page)

right under the new header, which is unsightly.  How do I get rid of that?

Answer (score 8):

Edit the page named "**MediaWiki:Mainpage**" on your wiki (you'll need admin rights for that) to set the new main page title.

For more information, see ["How do I change which page is the main page?"](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aFAQ#How_do_I_change_which_page_is_the_main_page.3F) in the MediaWiki FAQ.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Was getting sick of seeing that.

Answer (score 1):

You can hide the redirect text pretty easily with CSS[1].  Edit the page MediaWiki:Common.css in your wiki and add this:

```
.page-Main_Page #contentSub { display: none }
```

Where "Main_Page" is the name of your new main page. Also, if you really want to change the main page so that clicking on the site logo or the main page link in the sidebar takes you to a different page, you can edit MediaWiki:Mainpage[2] and enter in the name of your new main page.

[1] https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:CSS

[2] https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:FAQ#How_do_I_change_which_page_is_the_main_page.3F

Comment: Hi, I have two issues.  First, I only want to hide the redirect message on the main page and keep it on all other pages.  Also, link [2] doesn't explain much other than say "This can be changed by altering the contents of MediaWiki:Mainpage to point to a different title."

Comment: You can target a specific page with CSS but I'm not on a computer at the moment so I'll add an example tomorrow.  For MediaWiki:Mainpage, just edit that page and add the name of the page that you want to be the main page. So if you want the main page to be SuperNewMainPage, type that into Mediawiki:Mainpage and save it. Then clicking the site logo or the main page link will take you to that page.

Comment: But I already went a different route - 1) moved the main page to a new page, 2) set up a redirect, and 3) entered the #contentSub { display: none } code.  Should I undo all that?

Comment: @KnocksX yes you undo all that and just do what is said here https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:FAQ#How_do_I_change_which_page_is_the_main_page.3F

Comment: Yeah each page has the page name in the CSS.  I updated the answer with an example. But yes it would be better to undo all that and edit MediaWiki:Mainpage.